# Configuring Touchpad/Trackball for X

Tags: x11, gentoo, touchpad

I have just installed my gentoo with X11/Gnome. It works fine with the USB-Mouse, but neither the touchpad nor the trackpoint works.

The docs I found seemed to be outdated and were not mentioning the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d`. The laptop I am using is an Lenovo Thinkpad Edge E320.
`synaptics` is in the `USE` and the driver is installed.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I had disabled PS/2 mouse support in the kernel, because, as was my rationale, my laptop lacks a PS/2 plug.

Works good now.